Hosting multiple customer websites on Google App Engine with Different custom domains pointing to different services
I'd like to be able to spin up two websites.
I have changed my app.yaml, and the first one is spinning up correctly under site1-service.
But I need two different custom domains for this, so I can get the managed SSL cert(s).
When I add another custom domain, I can't choose a service.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Okay, I'll try that and see how it works. Thanks!

I was wondering how to set up a "dev" subdomain. This answers that.

Done, working beautifully, thank you! Now I just need to see if I can assign the domain name, too.

When you add a custom domain, the UI doesn't have a field to select a service.
You need to use dispatch.yaml to route traffic to different services e.g
  # send all example.com requests to default service.
  - url: "example.com/"
    service: default

  # Send all example2.com to second service.
  - url: "example2.com"
    service: second


Note: Haven't tried this for 2 different domains; have only tried it for a domain and a sub-domain i.e. example.com, app.example.com but I believe it's the same principle and should work

It works for two different domains. You have to have a dispatch.yaml only at the root of the default site.
dispatch:
  # send all default_site.com requests to default service.
  - url: "default_site.com/*"
    service: default

  # send all another_site.com requests to another_site service.
  - url: "nother_site.com/*"
    service: another_site

